# caffe `"Python"` layer not found?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I have installed caffe, uncommenting

```
WITH_PYTHON_LAYER=1
```

in `'Makefile.config'`

When I use a python data layer in my net.prototxt, it says

> ```
> Unknown layer type: Python
> ```

To cross check it in python interface,
I tried

```
import caffe
from caffe import layers as L
L.Python()
```

this seems to work ,no error then.
Where is the problem?

Comment: If you create a network with pycaffe (`L.Python()`) and really *run* it - does it work, or is there also an error?

Comment: Have you **compiled** caffe after setting `WITH_PYTHON_LAYER = 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out what layer types caffe has in python simply by examining `caffe.layer_types_list()`. For example, if you actually have a `"Python"` layer, then

```
list(caffe.layer_type_list()).index('Python')
```

Should actually return an index for its name in the layer types list.

As for `L.Python()` - this `caffe.NetSpec()` interface is used to programatically write a net prototxt, and at the writing stage layer types are not checked. You can actually write whatever layer you want:

```
L.YouDontThinkTheyNameALayerLikeThis()
```

Is totally cool. Even converting it to prototxt:

```
print "{}".format(L.YouDontThinkTheyNameALayerLikeThis().to_proto())
```

Actually results with this:

> ```
> layer {
>   name: "YouDontThinkTheyNameALayerLikeThis1"
>   type: "YouDontThinkTheyNameALayerLikeThis"
>   top: "YouDontThinkTheyNameALayerLikeThis1"
> }
> ```

You'll get an error message once you try to run this "net" using caffe...